# how to change state of any overlayItem on googlemap?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, overlay

I am able to display multiple overlayItems on Googlemap, now I want to change icon of any specific overlayItem (to show it is currently selected event). I want to do it through navigation buttons (next, previous) as on Google maps.

I am using [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) to display icons for OverlayItems.

Icon file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_icon"/>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/unselected_icon"/>
</selector>
```

code for getMarker method of OverlayItem is as follows.

```
@Override
public android.graphics.drawable.Drawable getMarker(int stateBitset){
    Drawable icon;              
    icon = this.mapActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.film_icon);
    icon.setBounds(0, 0, icon.getIntrinsicWidth(), icon.getIntrinsicHeight());
    return icon;
}
```

Now my question is how do I change the state of any overlayItem/Icon on map when user click on one of navigation keys?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the method setState(int id)?

Basically you can either use the predefined states defined as XML attributes for the StateListDrawable and set the state according to their IDs (i.e. android.R.attr.state_active) or you can add your own states using addState(int[] stateSet, Drawable drawable).

I did not try it myself so can't conclude it is working.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I am doing onclick of navigation key. I have tried setFocus(overlayItem) and also tried setMarker(Drawable), but No Luck :(